# Adding structure view to delphi 5 ide menu

Tags: delphi

Exist any IDE expert  to add the structure view to the delphi 5 ide menu?

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any expert with this capability, however you can always create your how using toolsapi it's not so hard but it will eat some time...

Comment: I'd look at CNPack first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ModelMaker Code Explorer](http://www.modelmakertools.com/code-explorer/index.html) is a very nice alternative for the structure view of your source code.
It works very nicely in Delphi 5.

--jeroen